# Numbers within strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a super simple BMI calculator, and as you can probably tell i'm new to Javascript. This is what I have so far in my HTML and Javascript files. What am I missing here to get the answer alerted? I know the problem lies in the Javascript somewhere; I'm missing something.
Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>BMI Calculator</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> BMI Calculator</h1>
      <form action="" method="get" id="bmi-form">
         <div class=section">
            <label for="q">Enter Weight in Pounds</label>
            <input type="search" id="weight" name="weight" required placeholder="type your weight">
            </br>
            <label for="h">Enter your Height in Inches</label>
            <input type="search" id="height" name="height" required placeholder="type your height">
         </div>

         <div class="button-group">
            <button type="submit" id="btn">Check</button>
         </div>
      </form>

      <div id="output"></div>
      <script src="javascript1.js"></script>
   </body>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
   var btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
       bmiForm =document.getElementById("bmi-form"),
       weight = document.getElementById("weight"),
       height = document.getElementById("height");

   btn.onclick = function calcBMI() {
       var bmi = weight*703/(height*height);
       alert('the answer' + bmi);
   };

   })();
```

Comment: share the code instead of a image of the code

Comment: consider pasting code rather than the image. or a jsFiddle would be even better

Comment: You are making it impossible for any search engine to ever find this question, unless you post the code in clear text.

Comment: Since you haven't fixed the question to include plain text, I'm afraid I will have to downvote the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that weight and height are dom element references not their values, to get their value you need to read the value property

so

```js
(function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
    bmiForm = document.getElementById('bmi-form'),
    weight = document.getElementById('weight'),
    height = document.getElementById('height');

  btn.onclick = function(e) {
    var bmi = weight.value / (height.value * height.value)
    alert(bmi);

    //to prevent the form submission
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})();
```

```html
<form id="bmi-form">
  <input id="weight" />
  <input id="height" />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e1a5r5pq/

Answer (score 26):

[image: Those are elements, not strings. You'll need]

<sub>(and please don't post code as pictures)</sub>

Comment: I don't even know what the question is (nor the answer). +1 for sheer "respond to screenshot of code with screenshot of code" badassery

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Oh my, the [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945/is-please-post-a-picture-a-non-constructive-comment?noredirect=1#comment309392_316945)…

Comment: For the curious, the original question looked like this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31822654/1

Answer (score 0):

```
bmiForm = document.getElementById("bmi-form").value;
height = document.getElementById("height").value;
weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
btn.onclick = function(e) {
var bmi = parseInt(weight) / (parseInt(height) * parseInt(height))
   e.preventDefault();
   alert(bmi);
}
```